# Inheriting the PyTorch DataLoader class

Tags: inheritance, pytorch, overriding, pytorch-dataloader

Can we inherit the DataLoader class? If so, are there any specific restrictions to it? 
I know we can do so for the Dataset class, but I need to know specifically about the DataLoader.

I have some requirements for a specific use case which involves overriding some of the DataLoader methods and adding some new ones.

Would really appreciate the help!
Thanks....

Comment: In general, yes. But you should consider if there's another way to implement the desired functionality (custom `Dataset` or `RandomSampler`), because the `DataLoader` involves parallel processing and if not done well this can cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: maybe you can make use of the ``collate_fn`` function of the DataLoader class

Comment: @Jan - Thats exactly what I want... I need to process the Dataloader multiprocessing "per-worker" `__get_item__` return value within the DataLoader module and further return the processed output to my main program. So, I dont think there's an easier way to do this than mocking the Dataloader module?

Comment: @TheodorPeifer - Please check my above comment. \ Not sure if we could do this using the `collate_fn` method?

Comment: From what it sounds like, @TheodorPeifer already had a pretty good idea. Maybe you just make a copy of the default collate (https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py#L84) with your modifications and pass it along to a vanilla DataLoader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Jan and @TheodorPeifer for your useful inputs..! :)

I was able to resolve this with a combination of `NamedTuple` returns from the dataset `__get_item__` calls with the "worker_specific_info"(`torch.utils.data.get_worker_info()`) along with a custom `collate_fn` implementation.